# How can I set up modal database postgresSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using postgres for my database and I am trying to create a rule for each team

Here is my following code in my database:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Team = sequelize.define(
    "Team",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      mission: DataTypes.STRING,
      agreement: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      tableName: "Teams",
      timestamps: true,
      indexes: [{ unique: false, fields: ["id", "title"] }],
    }
  );
```

[image]

So the agreement data type is my rules. Do I need to change it to array and create 4 rules in modal or is there anyways I can do it with string?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "modal database", but there is a "database to save data collected from a modal dialog".

Comment: How can I do it?